# Docker Compose - I can't access my Wordpress

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-config

I am trying to build three containers that are intertwined: MariaDB, Wordpress and Nginx.
Right now, mariadb is functioning, and Wordpress appears to be as well, since all of its data is being put in the database.
However, when I build my nginx, I get no errors, until I try to connect to wordpress by using my http://localhost or http://domain_name. It keeps saying that it is unable to connect.
This is my Docker-Compose:

```
services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    build: ./mariadb
    volumes:
      - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - inception

  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    build: ./wordpress
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - inception
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - inception
    depends_on:
      - wordpress

volumes:
  mariadb_data:
  wordpress_data:

networks:
  inception:
```

This is my Dockerfile for Nginx:

```
FROM        debian:bullseye

EXPOSE      443

RUN         apt-get update \
            && apt-get install -y \
                nginx \
                openssl \
            && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN         openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
                -keyout /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key \
                -out /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt \
                -subj "/C=PT/ST=Porto/L=Porto/O=42/OU=42/CN=ataboada.42.fr"

COPY        files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ENTRYPOINT  ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And this is my nginx-conf:

```
user                            www-data;
worker_processes                auto;
pid                             /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections          1024;
}

http {
    include                     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type                application/octet-stream;
    sendfile                    on;
    keepalive_timeout           65;

    ssl_protocols               TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    access_log                  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log                   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    server {
        listen                  443 ssl;
        listen                  [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name             ataboada.42.fr;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://wordpress:9000;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

obs.: it is a school assignment, so I have to use debian:bullseye as an image

Answer (score 1):

You are listening to port 443 on nginx conf:

```
    server {
        listen                  443 ssl;
        listen                  [::]:443 ssl;
```

but you are not publishing that port outside of the container. You can do it like this:

```
  nginx:
    ...
    ports:
      - 443:443
```

Furthermore, `http://localhost` might not work unless you have redirection from http to https enabled somewhere (some browsers might do that automatically). `https://localhost` will use the correct port 443.

Finally, your `server_name ataboada.42.fr;` block will anyway not work when using localhost, since it will only route traffic for requests to `https://ataboada.42.fr`. You can however use multiple server names in the same configuration:

```
server_name ataboada.42.fr 127.0.0.1 localhost;
```